# Linux Samba share on Windows only writeable manually not throught Netbeans application

Tags: linux, netbeans, permissions, samba, phpdoc

I got a perfectly working Samba share on my linux computer configured. I use it in Windows as Y: network drive. I can create folders, files what so ever. But when I use Netbeans to create a phpdocumentor entry I get write permission errors. And the weirdest thing is that when that error appears phpdocumentor has already created a few folders and files on the network drive.

I get the following errors from phpdocumentor:

> Fatal error: Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir 'Y:\classes\database\documentation\phpdoc\media\26d3399f63abd43a7d72f8c21440dcb0'

I believe I had a similar problem before with another php documentor. I can't figure out why I can create folders and files without a problem when I do it manually, but when PhpDocumentor tries it gives me write permission errors.

Anyone who could help me out?

The Linux Samba share is configured like this:

```
[share]
path = /var/www/domains/mydomain
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read list = roy
valid users = roy
write list = roy
create mask = 0755
```

Edit: It looks like PhpDocumenter is trying to write as a different user or something. PhpDocumentor works when I set the mask to 0777, but I don't want that as that would give me security risks.